# Ubuntu 17.10 WiFi Direct Printer?

Tags: wireless, wifi-direct

I want to use a wireless printer from another network, it's own. As of 17.10, if I connect to that network, the printer shows up almost instantly.

How can I configure Ubuntu to use the printer's network for that printer, even when connected to another WiFi network?

If it makes a difference, the printer is a Samsung M2825DW

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully established a "Wifi Direct" connection to a HP printer in Ubuntu 18.04 following [these](https://appuals.com/how-to-install-wireless-printers-on-ubuntu-16-04/) instructions.

The idea is to have both devices (computer and printer) connected to the same wifi network - namely the one you normally use to access internet on your computer.

(The printer will ***also*** show as a wifi network in the computer's list of wifi networks, but you don't need that here.)

After that, go to Printers section, Add, select “Network Printer”, than select "Find Network Printer" and just wait a bit until your printer appears under there.

[image]

Then select "Forward".

You will be asked to give it a name etc.

(With my printer I was not asked to enter a PIN in Linux, but this happened in Windows. At that point the printer displayed a PIN number, which then needs to be entered during setting/adding of the printer.)

When the process is successful, the "Wifi Direct" printer appears in the list of printers as a different printer beside the USB connected one.

[image]